# Disks attached to instance do not get deleted even when autoDelete is set to true

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am creating an instance with persistent disks attached to it, with 'autoDelete' set to true on all of the disks. The instance does not enter the "RUNNING" state due to invalid network interfaces, its status goes from "STAGING" to "TERMINATED"(I expect this to happen). When I delete the terminated VM instance the disks attached to it are not deleted.

I checked on the console before deleting the VM that on all disks, "When deleting instance" property is set to "Delete disk", and that all the disks are marked as in use by the VM and not detached.

Answer (score 0):

There is a check mark that prevent the disk from [accidental delete](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion), make sure it's unchecked

Comment: This one is to prevent accidental deletion of the instance itself, not the disks. I disabled this which is how I was able to delete the instance.

Comment: in this case is the disk shared between other instances?

Comment: No, they all belong to only one instance.

Comment: I think that your disk is suspended for some reason, it not clear what are you achieving by "its status goes from "STAGING" to "TERMINATED"(I expect this to happen)"

Comment: This is a scenario where a user accidentally enters an invalid IP address when creating a VM. I am trying to ensure garbage collection happens when the VM creation process fails due to incorrect inputs. The VM resource is created, associated disks are created and attached, but the VM cannot be provisioned due to the invalid IP,  which is expected. When I delete this VM now, the disks remain undeleted.